# Merge two objects but keep object children

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to merge two objects but keep their childen, `spread` and `Object.assign` do not seem to do that. I have found that they replace the children and remove those that don't match as well.

Please find below what I mean if it is not clear enough, I have not found a solution to this maybe that comes from my explanation.

```
const firstObject = {
    'united-states': {
        cities: {
            'new-york': {
                description: 'XXXX',
                image: 'URL 1',
            },
            boston: {
                description: 'XXXX',
                image: 'URL 1',
            }
        }
    },
    england: {
        cities: {
            london: {
                description: 'XXXX',
                image: 'URL 1',
            },
            manchester: {
                description: 'XXXX',
                image: 'URL 1',
            }
        }
    },
    france: {
        cities: {
            paris: {
                description: 'XXXX',
                image: 'URL 1',
            },
            lyon: {
                description: 'XXXX',
                image: 'URL 1',
            }
        }
    }
}

const secondObject = {
    'united-states': {
        cities: {
            boston: {
                description: 'YYYY',
                image: 'URL 2',
            }
        }
    },
    england: {
        cities: {
            london: {
                description: 'YYYY',
                image: 'URL 2',
            }
        }
    }
}

const mergedObject = {
    'united-states': {
        cities: {
            'new-york': {
                description: 'XXXX',
                image: 'URL 1',
            },
            boston: {
                description: 'YYYY',
                image: 'URL 2',
            }
        }
    },
    england: {
        cities: {
            london: {
                description: 'YYYY',
                image: 'URL 2',
            },
            manchester: {
                description: 'XXXX',
                image: 'URL 1',
            }
        }
    },
    france: {
        cities: {
            paris: {
                description: 'XXXX',
                image: 'URL 1',
            },
            lyon: {
                description: 'XXXX',
                image: 'URL 1',
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Nicolas V.H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just the spread operator, but you use it on the `cities` property, rather than the country. Note that any countries that exist in secondObject but do not exist in firstObject won't be counted. That's an easy one though

```js
const firstObject = {
  'united-states': {
    cities: {
      'new-york': {
        description: 'XXXX',
        image: 'URL 1',
      },
      'boston': {
        description: 'XXXX',
        image: 'URL 1',
      }
    }
  },
  england: {
    cities: {
      'london': {
        description: 'XXXX',
        image: 'URL 1',
      },
      'manchester': {
        description: 'XXXX',
        image: 'URL 1',
      }
    }
  },
  france: {
    cities: {
      'paris': {
        description: 'XXXX',
        image: 'URL 1',
      },
      'lyon': {
        description: 'XXXX',
        image: 'URL 1',
      }
    }
  }
}

const secondObject = {
  'united-states': {
    cities: {
      'boston': {
        description: 'YYYY',
        image: 'URL 2',
      }
    }
  },
  england: {
    cities: {
      'london': {
        description: 'YYYY',
        image: 'URL 2',
      }
    }
  }
}
 
let mergedObject = {}
for (let country in firstObject) {
let a=firstObject[country].cities, b=secondObject[country] && secondObject[country].cities || {};
   mergedObject[country] = {
    cities: { ...a,b}
  }
}

console.log(mergedObject)
```

Comment: I found that you forgot to spread `b` as well but it works like intended regardless. Thanks a lot!